# Full-Page Div Doesn't Show up

Tags: css, html

I have a HTML page with one div. The body code looks like this:

```
<div>
</div>
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
}

    div {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
    color:#000000;
}
```

I saw an example like this on another stackoverflow post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window).

I must be insanely stupid. Anyways, I made it so I could SEE the div, and it takes up the whole height now, but not the whole width. It takes up a little more than 1/2 of the space.

Comment: It's a white div, if it did appear what have you done to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will be helpful. Because "Viewport Units" currently don't have great browser support, you may want to use height 100% instead.
Viewport Unit Browser Support Table: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

If you want the div to cover areas that go below the viewport into the scrollable areas, try the code below:

```
html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:none;
height:100%;
}

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:none;
height:100%;
}

#wrapper-div {
min-height:100%;
}
```

The trick is setting the **height to 100%** on the **html** and **body** tags, and setting **min-height 100%** on the **wrapper div**. The div will expand 100% horizontally by default. Min and max width and height have great browser support, except IE6. (Note: If you still neet to support IE6, there is an easy hack that'll make it work. Add this to your wrapper-div, but your css won't validate`{*display:inline; *zoom:1;}`)

Browser Support for Min and Max Height and Width http://caniuse.com/minmaxwh

Here's a JSFiddle that has both the 100% and Viewport Units to play with:http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/ZHC5h/

---

If you want to use Viewport Units, try this code. It sets the width as vw, not vh:

```
body {
margin:0;
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
}

#wrapper-div {
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
background-color:#cccccc;
color:#000000;
}
```

Here's a quote from this article:http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css-viewport-units/

- 1vw: 1% of viewport width
- 1vh: 1% of viewport height
- 1vmin: 1vw or 1vh, whatever is smallest
- 1vmax: 1vw or 1vh, whatever is largest

Answer (score 0):

Your setting your background to white. Its not going to show. Try using #000 for black.

Answer (score 0):

It does work but like I mentioned: It's a white div, if it did appear what have you done to prove that?

Changing the background color proves it appears.

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/Cr3f2/

```
body {
    margin:0;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
}

    div {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
    color:#FF0000;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should change a bit the div attributes like this:

```
div {
height:inherit;
width: inherit;
color:#000000;
```

}

so that it will inherit the height and width of what is already indicated on the body css selector